# Не подключается к TCP серверу - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста,пытаюсь создать *"Чат-клиент"*. Дошел до того, что я создаю сервер и захожу в сам клиент с *первого* компьютера.

Но моя проблема заключается в том, что , когда я подключаюсь *вторым* компьютером к созданному серверу `(который запущен на первом компьютере)` ,то подключение **не происходит**.

Получается такая ситуация:

(сервер запущен)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первом компьютере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На втором:
 Но подключаясь(запуская только клиент), `Connect` не происходит. Номер порта и `localhost` остается прежним при подключение.
  *Чтобы добавить Connection в "сервер":*

```
void Widget::addConnection()
{

    QTcpSocket* connection = server->nextPendingConnection();

    connections.append(connection); //Them ket noi vao danh sach

    QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(this); //Tao bo dem du lieu cho connection nay

    buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    buffers.insert(connection, buffer); //Luu vao danh sach

    connect(connection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(removeConnection()));

    connect(connection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receiveMessage()));

}
```

Я не знаю, как лучше показать код, чтобы это легче воспринималось для понимания и, чтобы вы помогли решить проблему. Я выложу его так:

**Сервер:**

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vilapm4sr1laimi/AAD5G0USlLf5UayQq2zHb9ZUa?dl=0

**Клиент:**

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fx9jtzvtmeepzry/AABcDbvFU4ha4skHQP9AxK1la?dl=0

Собираю на Qt 5.3 под Windows.

Comment: На второй машине подключаться нужно не к `localhost`, это как минимум. Заодно проверьте, открыт ли нужный порт на обеих машинах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что `[localhost][1]` (он же 127.0.0.1) - это такой специальный адрес самой машины, на которой вы работаете. Так что запрос `localhost` на клиенте означает попытку подключения к серверу на этой же машине.

Так что в клиенте вам нужно указывать реальный адрес вашего сервера, ну, а сам сервер, соответственно, связывать для прослушивания с реальным адресом (`bind()` при работе с сокетами; как это решается в Qt - смотрите сами).

Comment: Все стало понятно, спасибо! Но можно спросить, откуда брать реальный адрес моего сервера? Я не разбираюсь в этом, хотелось бы понять. Если не трудно, объясните , пожалуйста..